# how to remove the starting and ending tags using python Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having difficulty in stripping the starting and ending tags from a json url. I've used beautiful soup and the only problem i'm facing is that i'm getting `<pre>` tags in my response. Please advise how can i remove the starting and ending tags. The code chunk i'm using is here:

```
page = Page( "link to json")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, "html.parser")
#fetching the response i want from the url it's inside pre tags.
json = soup.find("pre")
print(json)
```

Comment: Have you tried `soup.extract()`?

Comment: Yes it removes all the text inside the pre tag.

Comment: And have you tried `soup.text`? It removes all the tags from the soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `soup.text` to remove all the tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup("<pre>Hello, world!</pre>", "html.parser")
print(soup.find("pre").text)
```

Answer (score 2):

So Thanks to Demian Wolf. The solution is something like this:

```
page = Page( "link to json")
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, "html.parser")
#fetching the response i want from the url it's inside pre tags.
json = soup.find("pre")
print(json.text)
```